# Where is the error by checking user's role?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, coroutine

The Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    Besucher = message.guild.get_role(718944429888766044)
    Neuling = message.guild.get_role(721440088248025179)
    
    if message.content.startswith("!verify"):
        if  message.author.role == Neuling:
            await message.author.add_roles(Besucher)
            await message.author.remove_roles(Neuling)
            await message.author.send("Du wurdest Verifiziert")
            await message.delete() 
        else:
            await message.author.send("Du wurdest bereits verifiziert")
```

The Error:

```
File "Discord.py", line 23, in on_message
    if message.author.role == Neuling:
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'role'
```

What I need to check the user's role, because message.author.role == Neuling isn't it

Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```py
if Neuling in message.author.roles:
```

Because author has `roles` attribute, not `role`. You can read [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.roles)

Comment: Because roles is a list, using in essentially calls `==` on each one inside it and if ones true it will trip the if